# Bearer Token in ajax request header undefined.

Tags: jquery, ajax, auth0, bearer-token, request-headers

**Here I am making a call to a controller method GetAccessTokenAsync it returns a JSON result containing the access token from auth0**

```
function GetAccessToken() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://localhost:44301/Account/GetAccessTokenAsync",
    contentType: 'json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        JSON.stringify(data)
    }
});}
```

**Here is the controller method code**

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetAccessTokenAsync()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        return Json(accessToken);
    }
```

**Here is where I am trying to get the value from the ajax call above into the request header but it keeps coming back undefined. However that call does contain the proper access token it just isn't setting it properly**

```
function GetAll() {
var accessToken = GetAccessToken();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'json',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: false,
    url: "https://localhost:44348/api/v1/trialuser/1",
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:44301");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
            $('<tr>', { html: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($("#getAllTable"));
            $('#show').attr("disabled", true)
        })
    },

});}
```

**Any one else have this issue? and my knowledge on jquery and ajax calls is not extensive so any examples is appreciated thanks**

Answer (score 1):

You're function GetAccessToken() does not return anything or set any global variable.
So, your call to the function from the function GetAll() where you set accessToken = GetAccessToken() is setting nothing.

Either return something in the success event or set a variable value that both functions have access to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `GetAccessToken` method to return response.

```
function GetAccessToken() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://localhost:44301/Account/GetAccessTokenAsync",
    contentType: 'json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data)
    }
});}
```